# two dimensional array of buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create two dimensional array of buttons in windows form. I have to do it with for loops because I want to have an array of 100 buttons. But I cant get it to work. I tried with List> and with Buttton[,] but doesn't work. When I try like this:

```
private List<List<Button>> LEDarray = new List<List<Button>>();

        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            this.tempList.Clear();

            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                this.tempList.Add(new Button());
            }

            this.LEDarray.Add(tempList);
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                this.LEDarray[y][x].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
                this.LEDarray[y][x].FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
                this.LEDarray[y][x].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                xPos = xOffset + LEDsize * x + 20;
                yPos = yOffset + LEDsize * y + 20;

                this.LEDarray[y][x].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xPos, yPos);
                this.LEDarray[y][x].Name = "button" + y.ToString() + x.ToString(); 
                this.LEDarray[y][x].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(LEDsize, LEDsize);
                this.LEDarray[y][x].TabIndex = 0;
                this.LEDarray[y][x].UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(this.LEDarray[y][x]);
            }
        }
```

It only display the last row of buttons. So just fifth row and not the previous one. When I try similar with Button array it does not work at all. But array way is just SOS call. I want to do it with List so can you help me with code above to make it work?

Comment: code seems alright, maybe debugging is needed. Where are you calling the code and where temp list is declared?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change condition `for (int y = 0; y < 0; y++)` to `for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)` when adding buttons to controls.

Second problem is that you are clearing your tempList, reference to which you just added to `LEDarray`. Create new list for each row of buttons:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
{
     // tempList.Clear() - this will remove all buttons from previous row
     tempList = new List<Button>();

     for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)     
          tempList.Add(new Button());     

     LEDarray.Add(tempList);
}
```

Also I'd recommend you to increment `TabIndex` for buttons:

```
this.LEDarray[y][x].TabIndex = 10 * y + x;
```

And another advise - create your custom `LEDButton` class and use it:

```
public class LEDButton : Button
{
    public const int LEDWidth = 20;
    public const int LEDHeight = 20;

    public LEDButton()
    {
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);
        ForeColor = Color.Black;
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        Size = new Size(LEDWidth, LEDHeight);
        UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// initialize array
LEDButton[,] leds = new LEDButton[5, 20];
for (int y = 0; y < leds.GetUpperBound(0); y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < leds.GetUpperBound(1); x++)
        leds[y, x] = new LEDButton()
            {
                Name = String.Format("Button{0}{1}", y, x),
                TabIndex = 10 * y + x,
                Location = new Point(LEDButton.LEDWidth * x + 20,
                                     LEDButton.LEDHeight * y + 20)
            };
// add buttons to controls
for (int y = 0; y < leds.GetUpperBound(0); y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < leds.GetUpperBound(1); x++)
         Controls.Add(leds[y, x]);
```

Comment: but I meant to say it still doesnt work... It is just typo in post not my code

Comment: I tried to comment that line but stil display just last line.

Comment: try exactly like you said stil doesnt work... I think that buttons are actualy display but they are over the firs button in the fifth (only) line.

Comment: @gGololicic I tried and all works just fine - grid of 100 buttons is created

Comment: Indeed, the real problem here is using the same list, so all items were actually reference to the same list.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky thank you for this answer it started working. It is such a joy when professional programmer answer me. Your way is so more elegant. Thank you for that. And the problem as explained in comment was sam reference and with creating custom class that disapear. But however I am wondering why lists retain the same reference?

Comment: @gGololicic when you adding list to LEDarray, copy of list and it's items is not created. Only reference to list is passed. Thus you ended up with LEDarray having five references to same list of buttons.

Comment: If I had to do it this way how could I make five copies instead of same reference?

Comment: @gGololicic you have to pass different lists (and thus different references). Creating new list for each row is a solution. Each time you use `new` keyword - new reference is created.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to mix up the boundary values, try using *foreach* instead :-)

```
foreach (var row in this.LEDArray)
{
    foreach (var button in row)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Arguably, this communicates the intent of the code -- add all buttons in the collection -- better as well.

Comment: I think if you want to do this then you have to implement IEnumerator  interface.

Comment: What do you mean? The data structure needs implement IEnumerable, yes. You're using List<T> which does exactly that. Did my suggestion not work?

Comment: I tried to do that but it doesnt change anything, and yes sry List already implements that interface my bad.

Comment: So you add all elements of this.LEDArray and still only see the last row? Well, then there is something wrong with the way you populate that object :-)

Comment: All the code relevant to this problem is written in the question so if there is something wrong you can tell me what? but i cant figure out what? If i try to set button text to sum of all y in loop i get 10 which means that it loops through all the loops. I think problem is with button offset. But i dont know why?